# statusBarOrientation in iOS extension

Tags: ios, uiapplication

I'm having some trouble with my iOS extension. My library uses `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` to detect the orientation. `sharedApplication` isn't available in an iOS extension, so I thought I'd use a macro. It keeps throwing `sharedApplication is unavailable` though. What am I doing wrong? As you can see I have set the macro correctly. [image]

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation;

#if !defined(TARGET_IS_EXTENSION)
    orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
#else
    orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
#endif
```